# Internal Error: Unknown or unimplemented accessor type: 9

Tags: java, multithreading, oracle, jdbc, oracle11g

We are running a tomcat server with connection pooling and have recently been getting this error randomly.  It happens when we go to run a stored procedure in a package randomly.  I have tried to do some research into the problem myself, which lead to the source of this Java class which is where I assume the error is being dumped from: http://ora-jdbc-source.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/OracleJDBC/src/oracle/jdbc/driver/T2CCallableStatement.java

My question is: What is accessor type number 9?  It's not defined in the example class I provided, but whoever wrote that class obviously had to have a list of accessors and their corresponding numbers, of which I would like to see if possible, but have been unable to find.

I also have found other accessor type numbers in the error logs, for example: 6 has shown up also.

Update: I found a page detailing the datatypes and their code values, but datatype 6 and 9 apparently don't exist, making this error even weirder:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10646/oci03typ.htm#LNOCI030

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this issue is caused in Java when there are concurrency problems in the code.  We were getting the issue above when our program was running a thread pool and a programmer mistakenly assumed using the same connection in each thread only for SELECT statements would be okay (and according to the Java Connection class, it should technically be okay).  I guess this just goes to show that the Java Connection jar for Oracle DB is not thread safe.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced the same problem but the type was 6. The issue was caused by not closing (invoking .close()) the prepared statements and the result sets that hold the query results. Instantiating new prepared statements and result sets is not enough, you must close them always. Lesson learned.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be a catch all for when the driver isn't being used as expected.  Not fun.